# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'

Tags: visual-studio, tensorflow, python-3.5, channel

I am trying to download a channels package for making a chatbot by using google tensorflow. But, I am getting the following error:

```
3.5\twisted\words\im
    copying src\twisted\words\xish\xpathparser.g -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.5\twis
ted\words\xish
    running build_ext
    building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\twisted
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src\twisted\test
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\cl.exe /c /nologo
 /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DWIN32=1 -Ic:\python\python35\include -Ic:\python\pyt
hon35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include"
 -IC:\Python\Python35\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\VC\bin" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt
" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\amd64" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Micr
osoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\arm" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
\VC\bin\amd64_x86" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin
\amd64_arm" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_ar
m" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64" "-IC:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" "-IC:\Program F
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\amd64" "-IC:\Program Files
(x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\arm" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\M
icrosoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib" -IC:\Python\Python35\Lib "-IC:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\lib" /Tcsrc/twisted/test/
raiser.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'C:\Program'
, object file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'C:\Program' ignored
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Files', obj
ect file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Files' ignored
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '(x86)\Micro
soft', object file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file '(x86)\Microsoft' ignored
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Visual', ob
ject file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Visual' ignored
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type 'Studio', ob
ject file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file 'Studio' ignored
    cl : Command line warning D9024 : unrecognized source file type '14.0\VC\bin
\amd64_arm;', object file assumed
    cl : Command line warning D9027 : source file '14.0\VC\bin\amd64_arm;' ignor
ed
    raiser.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo
/INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\pyth
on\python35\libs /LIBPATH:c:\python\python35\PCbuild\amd64 /EXPORT:PyInit_raiser
 build\temp.win-amd64-3.5\Release\src/twisted/test/raiser.obj /OUT:build\lib.win
-amd64-3.5\twisted\test\raiser.cp35-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3
.5\Release\src/twisted/test\raiser.cp35-win_amd64.lib
    LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRT.lib'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\b
in\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python\python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file
__='C:\\Users\\krati\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-nzxnni5z\\twisted\\setup.p
y';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n
');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\kr
ati\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-3y_pe9kx-record\install-record.txt --single-version-e
xternally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\krati\AppData\
Local\Temp\pip-build-nzxnni5z\twisted\
```

I am using python 3.5 on Windows 7 64 bit operating system, Visual Studio Community 2017 and Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0 .I have tried everything, link the paths to the environment variable and include variable but still this error exists.

Can someone please help in resolving that..thanks in advance